# Printer rendering problem - probably page-size/scaling issue (A4 vs. Letter?)

Tags: drivers, printing, 15.10, canon

I'm using CUPS 2.1.3 on my Ubuntu 15.10 system to print stuff on a Canon-iR-ADV-C5235-5240 printer. I'm using the proprietary printer downloaded from Canon's webpage, newest version (Linux_UFRII_PrinterDriver_V310_uk_EN).

When I'm printing things like a pdf, there is a strange rendering error on them. Approx. at 90% of the page-width, there is some sort of shift/displacement of the contents, meaning text or image. It is NOT on the same area everywhere (like if it were dirt on the printer cylinders), but is about 90% with respect to the length of the text-column.

As a test, I printed a test page from the Ubuntu printer settings menu. It came out almost as expected, but with the one problem that the outer margin line on right side was a double line (space b/w lines approx. 7 mm).

My assumption is, that it has something to do with either conversion of letter to A4 (I'm printing on A4, which is selected in the printers configuration) or some other scaling event which takes place (unwittingly) in the background.

I switched CUPS into debug mode, started the printing of a test page, and afterwards saved all the error_log output regarding the print job. I've attached the error file below, however I omitted most of the "read/write print data" stuff, which is super redundant.

Thanks for any help!
Erik

CUPS error log:

```
I [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] Adding start banner page "none".
I [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] Adding end banner page "none".
I [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] File of type application/vnd.cups-pdf-banner queued by "jschlie1".
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] hold_until=0
I [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] Queued on "Canon-iR-ADV-C5235-5240" by "jschlie1".
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] time-at-processing=1457011771
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] 4 filters for job:
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] bannertopdf (application/vnd.cups-pdf-banner to application/pdf, cost 32)
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] pdftopdf (application/pdf to application/vnd.cups-pdf, cost 66)
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] pdftops (application/vnd.cups-pdf to application/vnd.cups-postscript, cost 100)
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] pstoufr2cpca (application/vnd.cups-postscript to printer/Canon-iR-ADV-C5235-5240, cost 0)
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] job-sheets=none,none
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] argv[0]="Canon-iR-ADV-C5235-5240"
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] argv[1]="388"
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] argv[2]="jschlie1"
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] argv[3]="Test Page"
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] argv[4]="1"
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] argv[5]="job-uuid=urn:uuid:25d8ac94-b47b-3049-4aba-5749cad166f5 job-originating-host-name=localhost date-time-at-creation= date-time-at-processing= time-at-creation=1457011771 time-at-processing=1457011771"
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] argv[6]="/var/spool/cups/d00388-001"
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] envp[0]="CUPS_CACHEDIR=/var/cache/cups"
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] envp[1]="CUPS_DATADIR=/usr/share/cups"
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] envp[2]="CUPS_DOCROOT=/usr/share/cups/doc-root"
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] envp[3]="CUPS_FONTPATH=/usr/share/cups/fonts"
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] envp[4]="CUPS_REQUESTROOT=/var/spool/cups"
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] envp[5]="CUPS_SERVERBIN=/usr/lib/cups"
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] envp[6]="CUPS_SERVERROOT=/etc/cups"
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] envp[7]="CUPS_STATEDIR=/var/run/cups"
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] envp[8]="HOME=/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] envp[9]="PATH=/usr/lib/cups/filter:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin"
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] envp[10]="SERVER_ADMIN=root@11800-pc28"
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] envp[11]="SOFTWARE=CUPS/2.1.0"
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] envp[12]="TMPDIR=/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] envp[13]="USER=root"
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] envp[14]="CUPS_MAX_MESSAGE=2047"
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] envp[15]="CUPS_SERVER=/var/run/cups/cups.sock"
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] envp[16]="CUPS_ENCRYPTION=IfRequested"
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] envp[17]="IPP_PORT=631"
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] envp[18]="CHARSET=utf-8"
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] envp[19]="LANG=en_US.UTF-8"
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] envp[20]="PPD=/etc/cups/ppd/Canon-iR-ADV-C5235-5240.ppd"
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] envp[21]="RIP_MAX_CACHE=128m"
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] envp[22]="CONTENT_TYPE=application/vnd.cups-pdf-banner"
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] envp[23]="DEVICE_URI=socket://10.208.30.10:9100"
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] envp[24]="PRINTER_INFO=Canon iR-ADV C5235/5240"
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] envp[25]="PRINTER_LOCATION="
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] envp[26]="PRINTER=Canon-iR-ADV-C5235-5240"
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] envp[27]="PRINTER_STATE_REASONS=none"
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] envp[28]="CUPS_FILETYPE=document"
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] envp[29]="FINAL_CONTENT_TYPE=application/vnd.cups-postscript"
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] envp[30]="AUTH_I****"
I [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/bannertopdf (PI    D 7035)
I [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf (PI    D 7036)
I [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftops (PI    D 7037)
I [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/pstoufr2cpca (PI    D 7038)
I [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] Started backend /usr/lib/cups/backend/socket (PI    D 7039)
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] pstoufr2cpca start.
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] pdftops - copying to temp print file "/tmp/01b7d56dcdcd1"
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] STATE: +connecting-to-device
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] Looking up "10.208.30.10"...
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] PDF template file doesn't have form. It's okay.
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] PI    D 7035 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/bannertopdf) exited with no errors.
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] PI    D 7036 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf) exited with no errors.
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] ATTR: marker-colors=#000000,#00FFFF,#FF00FF,#FFFF00,none
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] ATTR: marker-names='"Canon C-EXV 29 Black Toner"','"Canon C-EXV 29 Cyan Toner"','"Canon C-EXV 29 Magenta Toner"','"Canon C-EXV 29 Yellow Toner"','"Waste Toner"'
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] ATTR: marker-types=toner,toner,toner,toner,waste-toner
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] ATTR: marker-levels=96,97,97,97,-1
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] new_supply_state=0, change_state=ffff
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] STATE: -developer-low-report
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] STATE: -developer-empty-warning
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] STATE: -marker-supply-low-report
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] STATE: -marker-supply-empty-warning
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] STATE: -opc-near-eol-report
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] STATE: -opc-life-over-warning
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] STATE: -toner-low-report
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] STATE: -toner-empty-warning
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] STATE: -waste-receptacle-almost-full-report
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] STATE: -waste-receptacle-full-warning
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] STATE: -cleaner-life-almost-over-report
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] STATE: -cleaner-life-over-warning
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] new_state=8000, change_state=ffff
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] STATE: -media-empty-warning
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] STATE: -door-open-report
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] STATE: -media-jam-warning
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] STATE: -input-tray-missing-warning
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] STATE: -output-tray-missing-warning
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] STATE: -marker-supply-missing-warning
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] STATE: -output-area-almost-full-report
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] STATE: -output-area-full-warning
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] backendWaitLoop(snmp_fd=7, addr=0x563717781088, side_cb=0x5637174ce260)
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] Printer make and model: Canon ir-adv c5235/5240
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] Running command line for pstops: pstops 388 jschlie1 'Test Page' 1 'job-uuid=urn:uuid:25d8ac94-b47b-3049-4aba-5749cad166f5 job-originating-host-name=localhost date-time-at-creation= date-time-at-processing= time-at-creation=1457011771 time-at-processing=1457011771'
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] Using image rendering resolution 600 dpi
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] Running command line for gs: gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sDEVICE=ps2write -sOUTPUTFILE=%stdout -dLanguageLevel=3 -r600 -dCompressFonts=false -dNoT3CCITT -dNOINTERPOLATE -c 'save pop' -f /tmp/01b7d56dcdcd1
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] Started filter gs (PI    D 7040)
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] Started filter pstops (PI    D 7041)
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] Page = 595x842; 14,14 to 581,828
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] slow_collate=0, slow_duplex=0, slow_order=0
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] Before copy_comments - %!PS-Adobe-3.0
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] %!PS-Adobe-3.0
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] %%BoundingBox: 0 0 595 842
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] %%HiResBoundingBox: 0 0 595.00 842.00
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] %%Creator: GPL Ghostscript 916 (ps2write)
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] %%LanguageLevel: 2
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] %%CreationDate: D:20160303142931+01'00'
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] %%Pages: 2
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] %%EndComments
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] Before copy_prolog - %%BeginProlog
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] Before copy_setup - %%Page: 1 1
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] Before page loop - %%Page: 1 1
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] Copying page 1...
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] pagew = 566.9, pagel = 813.5
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] bboxx = 0, bboxy = 0, bboxw = 595, bboxl = 842
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] PageLeft = 14.2, PageRight = 581.1
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] PageTop = 827.8, PageBottom = 14.3
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] PageWidth = 595.0, PageLength = 842.0
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] opvpOpenPrinter(463)
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] CStubOpenPrinter(397)
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] opvpOpenPrinter(463)
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] CStubOpenPrinter(397)
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] Connecting to 10.208.30.10:9100
I [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] Connecting to printer.
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] Set job-printer-state-message to "Connecting to printer.", current level=INFO
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] STATE: -connecting-to-device
I [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] Connected to printer.
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] Set job-printer-state-message to "Connected to printer.", current level=INFO
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] Connected to 10.208.30.10:9100...
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:31 +0100] [Job 388] backendRunLoop(print_fd=0, device_fd=8, snmp_fd=7, addr=0x563717781088, use_bc=1, side_cb=0x5637174ce260)
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:32 +0100] [Job 388] Copying page 2...
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:32 +0100] [Job 388] pagew = 566.9, pagel = 813.5
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:32 +0100] [Job 388] bboxx = 0, bboxy = 0, bboxw = 595, bboxl = 842
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:32 +0100] [Job 388] PageLeft = 14.2, PageRight = 581.1
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:32 +0100] [Job 388] PageTop = 827.8, PageBottom = 14.3
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:32 +0100] [Job 388] PageWidth = 595.0, PageLength = 842.0
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:32 +0100] [Job 388] Read 8192 bytes of print data...
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:32 +0100] [Job 388] ATTR: marker-levels=95,95,96,96,-1
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:32 +0100] [Job 388] new_supply_state=0, change_state=0
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:32 +0100] [Job 388] new_state=8000, change_state=0
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:32 +0100] [Job 388] Wrote 8192 bytes of print data...
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:32 +0100] [Job 388] Read 8192 bytes of print data...
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:37 +0100] [Job 388] ATTR: marker-levels=95,95,96,96,-1
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:37 +0100] [Job 388] new_supply_state=0, change_state=0
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:37 +0100] [Job 388] new_state=8000, change_state=0
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:42 +0100] [Job 388] ATTR: marker-levels=95,95,96,96,-1
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:42 +0100] [Job 388] new_supply_state=0, change_state=0
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:42 +0100] [Job 388] new_state=8000, change_state=0
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:47 +0100] [Job 388] ATTR: marker-levels=95,95,96,96,-1
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:47 +0100] [Job 388] new_supply_state=0, change_state=0
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:47 +0100] [Job 388] new_state=8000, change_state=0
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:52 +0100] [Job 388] ATTR: marker-levels=95,95,96,96,-1
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:52 +0100] [Job 388] new_supply_state=0, change_state=0
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:52 +0100] [Job 388] new_state=8000, change_state=0
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:55 +0100] [Job 388] PI    D 7040 (gs) exited with no errors.
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:55 +0100] [Job 388] Wrote 2 pages...
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:55 +0100] [Job 388] PI    D 7041 (pstops) exited with no errors.
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:55 +0100] [Job 388] PI    D 7037 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftops) exited with no errors.
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:56 +0100] [Job 388] STATE: +cups-waiting-for-job-completed
I [03/Mar/2016:14:29:56 +0100] [Job 388] Waiting for printer to finish.
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:56 +0100] [Job 388] Set job-printer-state-message to "Waiting for printer to finish.", current level=INFO
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:56 +0100] [Job 388] PI    D 7038 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/pstoufr2cpca) exited with no errors.
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:56 +0100] [Job 388] ATTR: marker-levels=95,95,96,96,-1
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:56 +0100] [Job 388] new_supply_state=0, change_state=0
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:56 +0100] [Job 388] new_state=8000, change_state=0
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:56 +0100] [Job 388] PI    D 7039 (/usr/lib/cups/backend/socket) exited with no errors.
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:56 +0100] [Job 388] time-at-completed=1457011796
I [03/Mar/2016:14:29:56 +0100] [Job 388] Job completed.
D [03/Mar/2016:14:29:56 +0100] [Job 388] Removing document files.
D [03/Mar/2016:14:31:17 +0100] [Job 388] Unloading...
D [03/Mar/2016:14:31:28 +0100] [Job 388] Loading attributes...
D [03/Mar/2016:14:32:58 +0100] [Job 388] Unloading...
```